# Proguard - Obfuscate Android application as much as possible

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic2, proguard, android-proguard

I have the following `Android` application:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/zeuscronos/CallTheDog.git
$ cd CallTheDog/
$ npm install
$ ionic platform add android
$ cp __temp/* platforms/android/
$ ionic build android --release
$ adb install platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release.apk
```

The `Proguard` configuration file is:

```
platforms/android/proguard-rules.pro
```

You have it online here:

https://github.com/zeuscronos/CallTheDog/blob/master/__temp/proguard-rules.pro

Right now its content is:

```
-keep public class com.ionicframework.** { *; }
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-keep public class io.ionic.keyboard.** { *; }
-keep public class mx.ferreyra.callnumber.** { *; }
-dontshrink
```

As it is right now it doesn't do any obfuscation.

**My questions are:**

1- How do I configure these `Proguard` rules in order to `obfuscate` as much as possible?

2- How can I `keep the name of a method` (sometimes necessary to keep the consistency of the full application) but at the same time `obfuscating` the content inside like `local variables`, etc?

For example, looking at the following image, what about if I wanna keep the name of the methods: `execute` and `callPhone` but obfuscating at the same time its local variables?

[image]

Comment: You probably will want to read https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proguard already obfuscates as much as possible, usually what you mention are exceptions. I think this might do it for your example

```
-keepclassmembers class mx.ferreyra.callnumber.CFCallNumber { 
    boolean execute(java.lang.String, ...rest of signature);
    void callPhone(org.json.JSONArray);
}
```

Don't forget `minifyEnabled true` in gradle release build if you don't already have it.